# Installing/running nmap

Tags: nmap, kali-linux

I have a hyper-v machine running Kali Linux. I am as root attempting to run nmap.

When I attempt to launch it, I get an error saying:

"Error while loading shared libraries - and a bunch of garbled text after.

I've tried steps from here https://www.pentestgeek.com/tools/how-to-install-nmap

But I can't get the program to launch.

Anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: Can you give us details of what is the "garbed text" you mentioned? Also, which OS are you running?

Comment: Running Win 10 pro on host and latest version of Kali x64 Let me see if I can grab the particular code and copy in here thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

went to nmap and downloaded https://nmap.org/dist/?C=M&O=D ver nmap-7.60.dmg
run in dir file is downloaded and unzipped to.
./configure
Make 
Make install